# Video auto player ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Hello I want my video to appear automatically in my application, but I want the video player not to appear.I just started today.I wanted to ask you. I press a button and my other video plays automatically, can I do it with ionic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `autoplay` attribute on your video tag to play it automatically.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

you can remove controls by removing `controls` attribute.